# Azure AD B2C : An account could not be found for the provided user ID

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, reset-password

I am testing the "Password reset policy" functionality of Azure B2C AD, but I simply cannot get it to work. I receive the error "An account could not be found for the provided user ID." even though the user account I am trying to reset password for, does indeed exist.

Steps to repro:

1) Create user in Azure AD B2C

2) Go to "Users" > "Password reset - Properties" in the Azure portal, and enabled Self service password reset (not sure this is needed?)

3) Create password policy in the Azure AD b2c  using these settings:

- Identity providers = Reset password using email address (Local account)
- Application claims = Email Addresses
- Token config = Default
- Multifactor authentication = Off
- Page UI customization = Off
- Password complexity (Preview) = String (Default)
- Language customization = Not enabled

4) Save the policy

5) Click "Run now" on the password reset policy page

6) Enter email address of user created in step 1 and click "Send verification code"

7) Enter received verification code and click "Verify"

8) Enter email address and click "Continue".

The result for me, was the following error message: 
"An account could not be found for the provided user ID."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you creating the local account in step 1? (You don't need step 2.)

Comment: I clicked "new user" and as I then found out it did not create a local user. Thanks for the tip om step 2 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue should be caused by the step1.

I assume that you created user by clicking New user in Azure Active Directory. This kind of user is not a local Accounts in Azure AD B2C, it is a work or school account.It usually has `<...>.onmicrosoft.com` domain. This is for Azure AD, not Azure AD B2C. So, this passowrd reset policy for Azure AD does not work for Azure AD B2C.

You can see the details about the  difference between Local accounts from work or school accounts in [this FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs#what-are-local-accounts-in-azure-ad-b2c-how-are-they-different-from-work-or-school-accounts-in-azure-ad).

Local Accounts in Azure AD B2C should be created by Sign-up. And the users' password policy should be work with B2C password policy.

Additonial, you can also [use Azure AD work or School accounts to login Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom) by integrating Azure AD as a Social IDP, just like Google+, Facebook.

Comment: If my speculation is not  correctly, please let me know.

Comment: You are correct in regards to how I created the user in step 1. I will try to create the user using signup instead - thank you for clarifying!

Comment: It's my pleasure :-)

Comment: I am getting near identical problems, and it is FAR from clear what the difference between a "Local" user id and work and school accounts. AFAICT I have set up local ids and yet the password reset flow persistently fails to actually work. It verifies the email successfully, then asks for a user id, which it then can't find.,